# Spring oauth2 /token POST method not mapped

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've set up oauth server using org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.5.RELEASE lib. 
And I can't use password grant to authenticate client with resource owner credentials.
I use **RFC 6749**  - **4.3.  Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** - scenario.

### Sending similar request:

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

### I get

```
 HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

This endpoint is not mapped. 
Is it spring oauth2 issue?

Comment: why you call /token? i think it should be /oauth/token...

Comment: Why not make that an answer (since it is correct)?